# inputType={"number"}, Number dial pad not showing in ios but visible in android - React js

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap form control and input group.

I have created one  Component and used in my other modules.

The code is as follows :

```
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form"; 

export default class TextInput extends Component {

render() {
    var { value, maxLength, defaultInput, prefix, inputProps, placeholder, label, labelClass, formGroupClass, inputType, error, warning, onChange, disabled, mandatory } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Form.Group className={formGroupClass}>
          {label?
            (<Form.Label className={labelClass}>{label}
              {mandatory ? <span className="text-danger"> *</span>
                : ""}
            </Form.Label>)
            : ""
          }
          <InputGroup>
            {prefix && prefix !== "" ?
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Text>{prefix}
                </InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup.Prepend> : ""}
            <Form.Control isInvalid={!!error} className={warning ? "border border-warning " : undefined}
              disabled={disabled}
              type={inputType}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              value={value}
              defaultValue={defaultInput}
              maxLength={maxLength}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyUp(e)}
              {...inputProps}
            />            
          </InputGroup>
          <Form.Text className="feedback-warn text-warning">
            {warning}
          </Form.Text>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {error}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

}
```

And used this component in my other modules like this :

```
<TextInput
   placeholder={formData.mobileNum.label}
   inputType={"number"}
   error={formData.mobileNum.errMsg}
   value={formData.mobileNum.value}
   prefix={"+91"}
   maxLength="10"
   onChange={(text) =>
            changeValue(formData.mobileNum.propName, text)
   }
/>
```

The problem I am facing is in android device when I click on input field the number keypad is working fine.

In case of ios device `inputType={"number"}` is not working as I am not able to get the number keypad.

I tried some fixes but they affect the android also. I want that number keypad comes in both of the devices when I try to enter input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.
Done some silly mistake of not noticing the  {...inputProps} it contains all the remaining props for input.

In my TextInput component simply added the methods : pattern and inputMode

```
var { pattern, inputMode } = this.props


 <Form.Control isInvalid={!!error} className={warning ? "border border-warning " : undefined}
              disabled={disabled}
              type={inputType}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              value={value}
              pattern={pattern} // add this
              inputMode={inputMode} // add this
              defaultValue={defaultInput}
              maxLength={maxLength}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => this.onKeyUp(e)}
              {...inputProps}
            />
```

Then in my other files simply used these props like this :

```
<TextInput
   ..other props
   pattern={"[0-9]*"}
   inputMode={"numeric"}
   onChange={(text) =>
            changeValue(formData.mobileNum.propName, text)
   }
/>
```

pattern={"[0-9]*"} and inputMode={"numeric"} will force this ios devices to use number dialpad. Although pattern prop alone is enough inputMode is just a fallback if pattern doesn't work.

Note -> This will not affect the android behaviour with number keypad.

Alternative :

Instead of changing contents in the Main component we can utilise {...inputProps}

```
<TextInput
   ...other props
   inputProps={{ pattern: "[0-9]*", inputMode: "numeric" }} //add this
   onChange={(text) =>
            changeValue(formData.mobileNum.propName, text)
   }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput
   placeholder={formData.mobileNum.label}
   error={formData.mobileNum.errMsg}
   value={formData.mobileNum.value}
   prefix={"+91"}
   maxLength="10"
keyboardType="numeric" //add this
   onChange={(text) =>
            changeValue(formData.mobileNum.propName, text)
   }
/>
```

add keyboardType in your text input and remove inputType

Comment: Hi I am not using React Native, using React JS 
Please note -> When I am talking about ios and android I mean to say when I open my website in browser using ios and android device. 

keyboardType="numeric" is for react native. How to implement in react js.

Comment: oh ok ok,sorry I don't know about reactjs